# Dynamically adding check box to a panel

Tags: java, swing, components, ontology

I want to have check boxes generated dynamically with labels gotten from a list of pre-generated entities from an ontology. I have written the code to generate the check boxes and add them to a panel. However, the check boxes don't get displayed even after setting their `setVisible` to true. Please help go through my code to see if there is something I've left out.

```
public class ConceptsSelection extends javax.swing.JFrame {

/**
 * Creates new form ConceptsSelection
 */
public ConceptsSelection() {    
    initComponents();
}

Index in = new Index();
ArrayList<String> enti = new ArrayList<>();
private JCheckBox chk;
Set<OWLEntity> entities = new HashSet<OWLEntity>();
ArrayList<String> ents = new ArrayList<>();
JPanel panel;
private ArrayList<String> titles;
private ArrayList checks; //array of checkboxes
String prefix = "http://www.semanticweb.org/tobiomojola/ontologies/2018/0/untitled-ontology-42#";

public void setOntName()
{
    jTextField1.setText(in.fname.toString());
}

public int randomize()
{
    int len = ents.size();
    int result = (int)Math.ceil(Math.random() * len-1);
    return result;
}

public void addEnt(OWLOntology a)
{
    OWLOntology ontol = a;
    for(OWLSubClassOfAxiom f : ontol.getAxioms(AxiomType.SUBCLASS_OF))
    {
        if (f.getSuperClass() instanceof OWLClass && f.getSubClass() instanceof OWLClass)
        {
            //System.out.println(f.getSubClass() + " extends " + f.getSuperClass());
            entities.add((OWLEntity) f.getSubClass());
        }
    }
    for(OWLEntity e : entities)
    {
        ents.add(e.getIRI().toString().replaceAll(prefix, ""));
    }
}

private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    fillArray();
    createChecks(jPanel1);
}                                        

private void createChecks(Component x)
{
    jPanel1.setVisible(true);
    for(int i=1; i<6; i++)
    { 
        int b = randomize();
        chk = new JCheckBox(titles.get(b));
        jPanel1.add(chk);
        jPanel1.setVisible(true);
        chk.setVisible(true);

    }

    {
        //create a new checkbox for each string in the array
        chk=new JCheckBox(s);

        //add the checkbox to the panel
        jPanel1.add(chk);
        //add the checkbox to the array of checkboxes
        checks.add(chk);
    }

}

public void fillArray()
{
     titles=new ArrayList();
     for(String e : ents)
     {
         titles.add(e);
     }
}
```

Comment: [mcve] for best help, meaning you need to extract the essence of the problem into the smallest program that compiles and runs, removing all reliance on outside resources, such as text files and such.

Comment: Swing components are visible by default - setting them visible won't have any affect in this context - gut feeling `jPanel1` has not been added to the frame/content pane.  You should also be calling `revalidate` and `repaint` on `jPanel1` after you've updated it to trigger a layout and paint pass - this is VERY common question

Comment: *"..if there is something I've left out."* An MCVE (as detailed in first comment) & a question. Where is the MCVE? What is the question?